# Simulating robot_localization on pioneer3at with xsens 300 AHRS

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing `robot_localization` using the `receive_xsens` stack listed here: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/receive_xsens), and the `ros-pioneer3at` stack listed here: [link text](https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at).

I set up the frame id's to match those in the pioneer3at simulation stack as follows:

```
map_frame = Pioneer3AT/map
odom_frame = Pioneer3AT/odom
base_link_frame = Pioneer3AT/base_link
world_frame = Pioneer3AT/odom
```

I configured xsens imu to produce orientation, angular velocity, and acceleration. The `imu0` configuration looks like this:

```
<param name="imu0" value="/imu/data" />
```

I will incorporate p3at hardware later with wheel encoders. For now trying to fuse simulated odometry from the `ros-pioneer3at` stack. Specifically, I have configured the `odom0` as follows:

```
<param name="odom0" value="Pioneer3AT/pose" />
```

After configuring, I launch the `ros-pioneer3at` simulation, then launch the `receive_xsens` hardware, then launch the `ekf_localization` to fuse the sensor and simulation data.

There is no data being published to `odometry/filtered`. I am not sure where to start the debugging.

*-----edit 1-----*

Here is the node graph:

[rosgraph.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14222909183992352.png)

*-----edit 2-----*

Thanks for the insight!

Here is the script for /Pioneer3AT/pose:

```
import rospy
import tf
from nav_msgs.msg  import Odometry
def subCB(msg):
  P = (msg.pose.pose.position.x, msg.pose.pose.position.y, msg.pose.pose.position.z )
  Q = (msg.pose.pose.orientation.x, msg.pose.pose.orientation.y, msg.pose.pose.orientation.z, msg.pose.pose.orientation.w)
  br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
  br.sendTransform(P, Q, rospy.Time.now(), "/Pioneer3AT/base_link", "world")
if __name__ == '__main__':
  rospy.init_node('tf_from_pose')
  rospy.Subscriber("/Pioneer3AT/pose", Odometry, subCB)
  rospy.spin()
```

Also, here is the `ekf_localization_node` launch file I used to try and fuse the xsens imu hardware with the `ros-pioneer3at` simulation:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">
<param name="frequency" value="30"/>  
<param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>  
<param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>

<param name="map_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/map"/>
<param name="odom_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/odom"/>
<param name="base_link_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/base_link"/>
<param name="world_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/odom"/>

<param name="odom0" value="/Pioneer3AT/pose"/>
<param name="imu0" value="/imu/data"/>

<rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, true, 
                                true, true, true, 
                                false,  false, false, 
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false]</rosparam>

<rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, 
                               true,  true,  true, 
                               false, false, false, 
                               true,  true,  true,
                               true,  true,  true]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false" />
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="false" />
  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>


  <param name="odom0_pose_rejection_threshold" value="5"/>
  <param name="imu0_pose_rejection_threshold" value="0.3"/>
  <param name="imu0_angular_velocity_rejection_threshold" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold" value="0.1"/> -->

  <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">
[0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015]</rosparam>
</node>  
</launch>
```

Here are the sample message for `/imu/data`:

```
header: 
  seq: 53
  stamp: 
    secs: 1422541047
    nsecs: 981105890
  frame_id: /imu
orientation: 
  x: -0.0338176414371
  y: -0.0273063704371
  z: -0.260511487722
  w: 0.964491903782
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.00170594989322
  y: 0.000133183944854
  z: 0.0014496203512
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.690724253654
  y: -0.452333807945
  z: 9.75730419159
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

Here is a sample sensor message for `/Pioneer3AT/pose`:

```
header: 
  seq: 3203
  stamp: 
    secs: 1422541097
    nsecs: 747374621
  frame_id: /Pioneer3AT/odom
child_frame_id: /Pioneer3AT/base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.000293139455607
      y: 0.00299759814516
      z: 0.17000131309
    orientation: 
      x: 2.56361946104e-06
      y: 7.77009058467e-06
      z: 0.0016544693635
      w: 0.999998631331
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

---*edit 3*---

Still trying to make it work! I now started trying to get `odometry` working without an imu as you suggest. `robot_localization` improves the estimate as there is less drift than before.

Next, I attempt to integrate the imu. I have an updated launch file here:

```
<launch>

<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

  <param name="frequency" value="30"/>  
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1"/>  
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>

  <param name="map_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="/Pioneer3AT/odom"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="/Pioneer3AT/odom"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="/imu"/>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, true, 
                                  true, true, true, 
                                  false,  false, false, 
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, 
                                 true,  true,  true, 
                                 false, false, false, 
                                 true,  true,  true,
                                 true,  true,  true]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="true" />
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="true" />

  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

  <param name="odom0_pose_rejection_threshold" value="5"/>
  <param name="imu0_pose_rejection_threshold" value="0.3"/>
  <param name="imu0_angular_velocity_rejection_threshold" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold" value="0.1"/>

  <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">[0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015]</rosparam>

    </node>
</launch>
```

I connect *Pioneer3AT/base_link->/imu* with the following:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 /Pioneer3AT/base_link /imu 100" />
</launch>
```

The tf_tree is here with `ekf` node running: [image: image description]

One observation:
I notice that in RVIZ the wheels of the P3AT bounce up and down every few seconds. Is this likely because I am trying to set position/orientation with two broadcasters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201751/simulating-robot_localization-on-pioneer3at-with-xsens-300-ahrs/) by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-01-26**:
your topics might be namespaced to "pioneer3AT/imu/data" for example. can you post a picture of the ros node graph from rqt?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-01-26**:
Seems like you only have one input source (imu). I may be wrong, but im pretty sure you may need at least two. (wheel odometry, GPS, etc..)

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-26**:
@Tom Moore:

--`Pioneer3AT/pose` is of the type `nav_msgs.msg/Odometry`. I have included the scripts in my original post, along with my `ekf_localization_node`, and a sample message from each sensor.

--Still trying to get one sensor at a time up and running.

--Not able to run /imu/data alone.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-28**:
Would you mind just posting one example of each sensor message? You don't need to do record all of them with -p. Just do rostopic echo, copy a single message, and paste it in the question. I'm not trying to debug all your data. I just want to see one sample message of each. Thanks!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-29**:
Ha, no, sorry, I meant the entire message, complete with frame_ids. Like [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/198343/confused-about-robot_localization-usage/) (click the "more" link in the question to see the whole thing).

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-08**:
What do you mean by "set position/orientation with two broadcasters"? Do you still have the P3 node broadcasting the *odom*->*base_link* transform as well?

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-02-08**:
I meant that `ekf_localization` is broadcasting *odom->base_link* and `Gazebo_Bridge` is broadcasting *odom->base_link*. I could not realize another way to provide *odom* data in my current setup. For now, I am fusing simulation *odom* data, with *xsens* data. Later planned to use wheel odometry data.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-09**:
What do you mean by "provide odom data"? You simply can **not** have two different nodes publishing the same transform. If you are running `ekf_localization_node`, it is providing your odometry message and the *odom*->*base_link* transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One data source will work.

What message type is `Pioneer3AT/pose`? If it's a `PoseWithCovarianceStamped`, then your configuration is wrong. Change it to

```
<param name="pose0" value="Pioneer3AT/pose" />
```

When in doubt, start with one sensor at a time. Get your pose data working, then add the IMU, etc.

EDIT: Also, the best thing to do is paste your entire `ekf_localization_node` launch file, and post a sample message from each sensor.

EDIT 2: Your IMU data appears to be in the `/imu` frame. Are you providing a transform from `/imu` to `/Pioneer3AT/base_link`? Also, you want to make sure that your Pioneer code is **not** broadcasting a `/Pioneer3AT/odom`->`/Pioneer3AT/base_link` transform.

EDIT 3: So I ran your bag file with the launch file you posted. I **am** definitely getting publications on `/odometry/filtered`, though the only data going into it is IMU data, because your bag didn't have any Pioneer odometry messages in it. If you're still having trouble, do this for me:

1. Set up your robot as before, without `ekf_localization_node` running. Bring everything up.
2. Start bagging everything.
3. Drive your robot in some pattern. A square works well. Make note of how you drove the robot (e.g., clockwise turns, leg lengths, etc.).
4. Post the bag, and let me know what, if any, output you were getting from `ekf_localization_node`.

EDIT 4: If you download the bag file you posted, and then start playing it back, and do `rostopic echo /Pioneer3AT/pose`, you'll see that no messages are published to /Pioneer3AT/pose (or you can just do `rosbag info` on the bag and see that no odometry messages are in there). Now run your system live, and do `rostopic echo /Pioneer3AT/pose`. If nothing comes out, then you've got a problem with your odometry publishing.

EDIT 5 (in response to comment): here's a screenshot of the output of your bag after about 30 seconds. Is this what you mean by "light years"?

[image: image description]

This is exactly what I would expect to see from a single IMU being used for your state estimate. You're fusing linear acceleration, which is typically pretty noisy, and is clearly not zero-mean in this case, as you are creeping along in all three dimensions. If you have no other measurements from other sensors to help, small errors in your IMU acceleration will accumulate and lead to false velocity, which will continue to grow infinitely, and your position will as well.

Long story short: you can't get a good state estimate with a single IMU by itself.

Re: the *odom*->*base_link* transform, see [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). ROS assumes three principal frames: *map*, *odom*, and *base_link* (or whatever naming scheme you want). The purpose of packages like robot_localization is to provide two things:

1. A `nav_msgs/Odometry` message with the robot's current pose estimate
2. A transform from *odom*->*base_link* **or** a transform from *map*->*odom*. With your configuration, we are going from */Pioneer3/odom*->*/Pioneer3/base_link*. This transform will contain effectively the same data as the message, but will be used by `tf`. Note that the transform from the `odom` frame to the `base_link` frame is equivalent to your pose in the world (technically, it's the inverse, but when you put the transform together, you use the same data as your message).

Now, `tf` does not like two different nodes broadcasting the same transform. The Pioneer node you're using has an option that allows it to broadcast the */Pioneer3/odom*->*/Pioneer3/base_link* based on its raw wheel odometry. You want a better estimate of your position, so you fuse the raw wheel odometry with IMU data. This produces the two outputs above.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-28**:
I am not providing a transform from `/imu` frame to `/Pioneer3AT/base_link`. I believe that I had the broadcaster on from `/Pioneer3AT_Gazebo`, broadcasting a `/Pioneer3AT/odom`->`/Pioneer3AT/base_link` transform. Sorry about that.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-29**:
No worries! Try providing the */Pioneer3AT/base_link*->*imu* transform (you can probably just use `tf`'s `static_transform_publisher`). Then disable the broadcast of the *odom*->*base_link* transform from Gazebo. Let me know if that helps.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-30**:
I tried `tf`'s `static_transform_publisher` for *Pioneer3AT/base_link->imu* while disabling broadcast of *odom->base_link*. */odometry/filtered* publish's pose and orientation data. Both grow without bounds, and seem unaffected by the imu. Would you have any other suggestions? Greatly appreciated!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-30**:
Can you run your system *without* running anything from `robot_localization`, and then post a bag? Thanks!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-30**:
Unless you have a Kinect/camera/LIDAR, then yes.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-30**:
Tom: Here is a link to the bag file: [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B17BNBr-HwSZcFBlSlJtQlNSQUU/view?usp=sharing)

Please let me know if I can provide anything else....Is it best to post in the question? Thanks!

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-02-02**:
Here is link to bag file: [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B17BNBr-HwSZNEVzSEd1Z28zQnc/view?usp=sharing). I turned off *Pioneer3AT/odom*->*Pioneer3AT/base_link*. Just using imu sensor for now. I moved forward a few meters, turned CCW, forward a few meters, CCW, forward a few meters.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-02-03**:
The bag file is in the previous comment. This time I surely had *nothing* running from `robot_localization` (Sorry about the previous bag file that did), and I got no output from `robot_localization`. Thanks!

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-02-03**:
Right. I tried not publishing odometry data to `Pioneer3AT/pose` in order to work with just the imu sensor. Do I need to have that published? Thanks!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-03**:
I guess it depends on what remains to be answered in your question. When I use your launch file, the IMU data is clearly being integrated and a state estimate is being produced (i.e., the /odometry/filtered message gets published). Is that not the case for you?

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-02-03**:
The IMU data is being integrated in my case too, but the state estimate is off by light years. Also, it is unaffected by any motion of the IMU. I turned off the *odom->base_link* transform, and I am not sure how to get pose data without that broadcast.